# Como passar mais de um parâmetro em um método paint() em Java?

Tags: java, swing

Estava desenvolvendo um projeto onde preciso sobrescrever o método paint(), porém o método paint() só recebe como parâmetro um objeto Graphics.
O que eu preciso fazer é criar um método paint que receba dois parâmetros e utilize objetos do tipo Image pertencentes ao objeto Outro para desenhar na tela, por exemplo`

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Desenho extends JPanel{

       public void paint(Graphics g, Outro o){
           Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
           g2d.drawImage(o.getImagem(), o.getX(), o.getY(), null);
       }
}
```

após isso eu precisaria chamar esse método e passar os parâmetros.

```
Outro o2 = new Outro();
Graphics gh = new Graphics();     // Não posso criar um Graphics assim pois Graphics é classe    abstrata.
paint(gh, o2);
```

O problema é que não posso criar um objeto Graphics fora do método e assim não consigo criar o método com mais de um argumento.

Se alguém souber como fazer isso ou tenha uma ideia diferente que chegue ao mesmo resultado e possa me ajudar, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Se você está querendo sobrescrever [`paint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint-java.awt.Graphics-), e tudo indica que sim, não dá, precisa achar outro caminho.

Comment: É exatamente isso e tive o mesmo problema com diversos métodos que recebem 'Graphics' como argumento.

Comment: É difícil entender o que está fazendo, mas precisa organizar a classe para funcionar de outra forma, e não precisar que o `paint()` recebe esse parâmetro, ou seja, precisa estar disponível na instância para ele pegar ali dentro.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma para contornar esta questão é tornar o `Outro` em uma propriedade da classe.

E quando instanciar a classe passa lo no construtor!

Segue um exemplo:

```
public class Desenho  extends JFrame{

    private Outro o;

    public Desenho(Outro o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method s
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2d.drawImage(o.getImagem(), o.getX(), o.getY(), null);
        super.paint(g);
    }
}
```

Não sei se esta forma atende o escopo da sua aplicação, mas é uma solução!